# How to trigger hard refresh when redirecting to a different page in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, next-router, next-link

I have a `<Link>` to a certain page on my Next.js website. Upon clicking it, I want the webpage to hard reload after it redirects to the destination page (whether it reloads before or after the redirect is not important). I have tried using `router.push` as well but a hard refresh does not occur. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to refresh the page on load use simple anchor tags,
if you want more control over reloading the page,
Refer this:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerreload

Answer (score 7):

Another solution to do hard reload on navigation/redirect in next.js is to use native browser location API, like this

```js
function onClick() {
  window.location.href = "/destination"
}

<Link onClick={onClick}>link</Link>
```