# NextJS Force Reload of Page from Link

Tags: next.js

I have a menu header with Links pointing to different pages, e.g.

```
<Link href="/module1" key="resourceMenu1">
  Module 1
</Link>
```

Each module corresponds to a `/moduleN/page.tsx`. It contains two embedded sub-components, either a `<SearchForm>` or `<ResultsPage>`. These are like pseudo-pages on the Results page, rather than real separate pages.

```
{!showSearchFormFlag
 ?
   <SearchForm ... />
 :
   <Results .../>
}
```

Since the URL doesn't change, if the user is showing Results and re-opens the page from the menu bar, it doesn't go back to the Search Form. It needs to show the first form when opened from the menu. (Manually refreshing in the browser works.)

Some threads suggest [JS workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75625542/1005607) but I don't want to hack each `Link` with an `onClick=..` with `window.location.href`. It's too much of a hack and bypasses NextJS. I also can't do query params since the URL stays the same, `module1?screen=1`. Any other tips?

Comment: Reminds me of this video going over Next caching. Might be helpful. https://youtu.be/_yhSh4g0NSk?si=bjJZfK-9TEh-aCHI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved this issue. I had to manually refresh in JS `window.location.href`, but I didn't want to modify all my `Link`s and cause flickering for each one. For the most part NextJS' Router has to work smoothly as usual. I restricted this new code only to the specific case of the `Link` *pointing to the same URL as the current window*. To handle this I added an Effect that specifies a `mousedown/keydown` listener on initialization, outside of all my links.

```
  // mousedown listener
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', (ev) => {
      const elem = ev.target as HTMLElement;
      // Condition to identify selected Menu A-link
      if (elem.nodeName === "A" && elem.classList.contains("someIdentifiableClass")) {
         const linkElem = ev.target as HTMLAnchorElement;
         if (linkElem.href === window.location.href) {
             window.location.href = linkElem.href; // Force reload only if same
         }
      }
   })
  }, []);

  // keydown listener
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (ev) => {
      const elem = ev.target as HTMLElement;
      // Condition to identify selected Menu A-link
      if (elem.nodeName === "A" && elem.classList.contains("someIdentifiableClass")) {
        const linkElem = ev.target as HTMLAnchorElement;
        if (linkElem.href === window.location.href) {
           if (ev.key === 'Enter') {
              window.location.href = linkElem.href; // Force reload only if same
           }
        }
      }
    })
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with why it acts different than expected when re-opened. The example you gave seems to be conditional on a boolean. Is that boolean reset every time the menu bar is interacted with to re-open the page? I may not be understanding the problem or may be missing some part of the problem.